# Java interface for manual serialization

Tags: java, serialization, architecture, mixins

I have some data-structure realizations, here is scheme

```
interface Structure {
  //some methods
}

class SomeRealization implements Structure {
  ...
}

class AnotherRealization implements Structure {
  ...
}
```

I serializing them both manually in form of `char array` with usage of `FileChannel` and `CharBuffer`. Yes, I can do the same by `writeObject` method, but `nio` is faster than `ObjectOutputStream`.

I wanted to define mixin intended to hold serialization/deserialization methods in purpose of making project expandable and because of different algorithms for serialization/deserealization of implementations. Something like this

```
interface StructureIO {
  void saveStructure(String filename);
  Structure loadStructure(String filename);
}
```

So if I implement this interface for realizations of Structure I will need instance for calls of `loadStructure(String filename)` method and this isn't suitable, in fact this is terrible.

Yes, I can define `loadStructure(String filename)` method as static in Java 8, but it will give me nothing because static methods can't be overriden.

So if you have some ideas, please write
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: When I saw "interface for manual serialization" the first thing I thought of was [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)… which is an interface that allows an implementing class to provide manual serialization.

Comment: @VGR nio is faster then Externalizable thats why I don't want to use  Externalizable

Comment: @VGR rather `nio` is faster then `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: How much faster?  Disk I/O is likely to be far more of a bottleneck.  Even if this does grant a gain in performance, will you be doing this loading and saving often enough to need it?  Is it worth the additional complexity?

Comment: @VGR about additional complexity you're totally right, but what if I need to store char array with size of 1,000,000 elements? ok, I'll do some tests and respond to you :)

Comment: @VGR lol, 1,000,000 chars writes to fiel for 10.617105 ms. Of course I'll make test for ObjectOutputStream, but I think your answer is the best way to go

Comment: @VGR the results is next for 1,000,000 chars `nio` - 14.91 ms; `ObjectOutputStream` - 75.23 ms (in 5 times bigger!), but when I've increased size of array to 10,000,000 the results was next `nio` - 162.46 ms; `ObjectOutputStream` - 243.62 ms

Comment: @VGR add your comment as an answer, I want to accept it as right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has an interface for manual serialization:  [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html).

Even if java.nio is faster (which is the subject of many other Stack Overflow discussions), it's not likely to be significantly faster.  Disk I/O is likely to be far more of a bottleneck.

Even if a custom approach does grant a gain in performance, I suspect you won't be doing this loading and saving often enough to need it.  For those reasons, I would just use Externalizable, and avoid the additional complexity.

Comment: This does not solve the decision problem: which type to instantiate before calling the deserialization method?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not willing to tolerate `loadStructure` -- which I suppose you could do by letting objects be created uninitialized then initializing them with `loadStructure` -- then you won't be able to enforce deserializability as part of the interface contract.

This isn't necessarily a disaster, however, as it doesn't necessarily make sense to have generic deserialization in the first place.  When you're looking at a serialized stream of bytes (or chars, I suppose, in your case), you need to know what type it is to make sense of it.  So there isn't necessarily a need for generic deserialization, you'll just have to write `MySpecificClass.deserialize(InputSourceType source)` (substituting in a filename, an `InputStream`, or whatever abstraction you think appropriate).

Comment: *you need to know what type it is to make sense of it* - my point exactly, put in a nice way :)

Comment: can you write some pseudo-code or scheme of code, please, because I don't understand how you imagine it all

Comment: the easiest way to go as far as I see is add uninitialized public instance to both implementations

Comment: rathe to guarantee possibility of their creation

Answer (score 2):

If you could override this static method, how would you use it anyway? The decision about which class to instantiate has to be taken before you call the method, yet you would need to start reading the file to do so.

My point is, what you want here is a way to read a file and create a Structure object:

```
Structure s = loadStructure(filename);
```

The problem is, this method needs to know all the child classes it can build, and needs to read which one it *should* build from the file itself.

Therefore, you need some common code somewhere to start reading the file, and call the static method of the right class depending on the type information in the file. Use a factory class that knows them all, and allow child classes to define the static method by themselves, without enforcing it via an interface (which you don't need anyway).

Comment: creating common class and defining which type of Structure I'm loading in his load method is bad idea, cause user can not expand project without modifying code of such class.

Meaby I understand you wrong, so I apologize

Comment: @MikeHerasimov You understood right. But you can't have a method that takes any file and returns an object of the right Structure subclass without doing so. You will have to have some common code at some point making that decision. The accepted answer is only solving the type-specific part in the implementation of the common method, but it does not allow you to avoid that aspect.

Comment: uhh, I understand now, you mean I need some code to understand which type of Structure file holds in purpose of returning to user right type (+1)

Comment: I can simply store string with name of class or single byte, which defines what type file holding, but here comes another trouble how to make it all expandable

Comment: @MikeHerasimov Exactly. You need type information in the file, and this shouldn't be a problem to store. My point is that you'll need code to read it and choose the type from there, and that is before polymorphism can play its role.